# Android: Is there a possibiltiy to detect which app is sending sound?

Tags: android, audio

Is there a possibiltiy to detect which app is sending sound? I only found a solution to recognize there is sound playing, but not which app is playing it.

Comment: Apart from custom made libraries, I don't think there is something you can do, sadly.

Comment: Also, in Android Q your permissions are limited, so you can't just access root permission to make something out of it.